# Why I have I lost the function and only get the value after I save and reopen the spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using desktop Excel on Windows.

I have a single spreadsheet. In one cell, I have written a formula `=countif(a1:a10, "*1")`. I get a correct value.

My question is, why have I lost the function and get only the value after I save and reopen the spreadsheet?

Comment: Did you save as the Excel format, or some other format that is not capable of keeping formula (e.g. CSV, TXT etc)?

Comment: what do you mean by lost the  formula & only get value? Did the formula disappears ? rewrite your formula, since it's preceded with ' sign which convert it  into Text ans also the wild card "*1" is wrong !!

Comment: @n179911, could you please write what answer your formula **'=counif(a1:a10, "*1")"** has given & what you are trying to achieve, please upload the screen shot also !!

Answer (score -3):

The formula you have used `'=counif(a1:a10, "*1")"`

should to be written like, `=counif(a1:a10, "*1")`.

*And it suggests that, you are trying to count all number which ends with **1** . In this case you need to use the following array formula.*

```
{=IF(RIGHT(A1:A5,1)="1",COUNT(A1:A5),"")}
```

**Note:**, Finish this formula with CRTL+SHIFT+ENTER, & adjust the data range as you need.

[image]

Comment: You don't answer the question (My question is, why have I lost the function and get only the value after I save and reopen the spreadsheet?) but suggest improvements where OP's formula works as expected.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, at the beginning of my answer I've mentioned that what basic mistake OP has commited and wrote the formula like **'=counif(a1:a10, "*1")"** and this was the reason Excel considers it  asText rather than Formula. I'm sure OP misunderstood & written that, " Why I've lost my Formula" !!

Comment: OP clearly wrote that the formula had worked correctly before reopening the workbook, `"`s just remained in the question during edits.

Comment: I've edited the question just now, is it more clear now?

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, do you also think that, **'=counif(a1:a10, "*1")"** really works ??

Comment: If OP wrote "I get a correct value." that means works, yes. There is much higher probability formula is entered by hand incorrectly here, than OP would add an entire sentence by mistake... Please don't look for mistakes where there aren't but focus on the question.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, YES dear that's Y I've assumed that OP is trying to count the number ends with 1 & use WILD CARD incorrectly also ! And how could one ignore the basic mistakes, especially when Formula Fails to co-relate the KEY ISSUE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76962/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-mate-juhasz).